# Coroutines and unit tests - Why is my test returning two identical lists

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm working with a Kotlin program where a user votes on two items, for simplicity sake imagine drawing two playing cards. The user votes on which playing card they like best, that list gets ranked, and those rankings can be compared against a friend.

I'm writing an algorithm in ValueRepo.kt to decide which cards to show a user in order to get the most meaningful shared results between two users the fastest.

In DeckUnitTest.kt I'm trying to unit test two users playing a game 100 times and seeing how much overlap their choices have.

When my test runs it produces two identical lists, so the comparison is always 100%.  They should be voting randomly and drawing semi-randomly so it shouldn't be creating identical lists.

**HumanValue.kt**

```
data class HumanValue(
    var id: Int = 0,
    val name: String? = "error",
    val priority: Int = 9,
    var gamesPlayed: Int = 0,
    var gamesWon: Int = 0,
    var gamesLost: Int = 0,
    var gamesTied: Int = 0,
    var rating: Int = 0,
    var kFactor: Double = 0.0)
}
```

**DeckUnitTest.kt**

```
class DeckUnitTest {
  val repo = ValueRepo()

  private fun runGame(list: List<HumanValue>): List<HumanValue> {
    val drawn = repo.drawTwo(list)
    list.find { it.id == drawn[0].id }?.let {
      println("Winner: ${it.name}")
      it.gamesPlayed++
      it.gamesWon++
      println("Winner: $it")
    }
    list.find { it.id == drawn[1].id }?.let {
      it.gamesPlayed++
      it.gamesLost++
      println("Loser: $it")
    }
    return list
  }

  @Test
  fun testDeck() {
    var userOne = repo.freshDeckObject()
    var userTwo = repo.freshDeckObject()
    runBlocking {
      (0..100).map {
        async {
          println("Ran $it games")
          userOne = runGame(userOne) as ArrayList<HumanValue>
        }
         async {
           userTwo = runGame(userTwo) as ArrayList<HumanValue>
         }

      }.awaitAll()


      println("Starting job 2")
      val existing1 = userOne.filter { it.gamesPlayed > 0 }.map { it.id }
      val existing2 = userTwo.filter { it.gamesPlayed > 0 }.map { it.id }
      val mutual = existing1.intersect(existing2.toSet())

      assertTrue(existing1.isNotEmpty()) //Passes
      assertTrue(existing2.isNotEmpty()) //Passes
      assertTrue(mutual.isNotEmpty()) //Passes
      assertNotEquals(userOne, userTwo) //Fails
    }
  }
}
```

**ValueRepo.kt**

```
class ValueRepo {

  fun freshDeckObject() = hvObjectList

  private val hvObjectList = arrayListOf (
    HumanValue(0, "acceptance", 0),
    HumanValue(1, "accomplishment", 1),
// So on and so forth, a list of 250 items
    )

  fun drawTwo(valueList: List<HumanValue>): List<HumanValue> {
      val splitList = valueList.groupBy { it.priority }
      val average = splitList.values.map { list -> list.map { value -> value.gamesPlayed }.average() }.average()
      val topHalf = valueList.filter { it.gamesPlayed <= average }.sortedBy { it.priority }.chunked(2).flatten()
      Logger.d(topHalf)
      return topHalf.shuffled().take(2)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`runGame` returns the same list instance that was passed to it, so no matter how many simulations you run, you always have the original list at the end. And since both `userOne` and `userTwo` start with the same list instance, they end with the same list instance. Your final assertion is comparing `hvObjectList` to itself.

Comment: But I'm modifying an item within that list before returning it.  Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Comment: Ok got it, I was still using a reference.  I'm still not sure how to get a new version of an object from a repo, but I just gave them their own repo and that works.

Comment: I’m not sure what your algorithm is trying to do but it doesn’t really make sense that your function returns the list that was passed to it without modifying it. What’s the point of returning it? The caller obviously already has a reference to it. You can copy a List into a new List instance by calling `toList()` or `toMutableList()` on it.

Comment: To do a deep copy of a list, it should be `fun freshDeckObject() = hvObjectList.map { it.copy() }`